# delete parent halfway animation, keep position and more

Tags: animation, parent

a new semi blender noob here..

I have a flying cube animation running, and the cube has parented cube face panes/images. I need, let's say at frame 200, the 'faces' to lose the parent and fall down on the ground.
I can't get it to lose the parent at a specific moment.
Also tried with faces as 'child of'..
but then the position is gone etc..
I'm stuck here..
Any help would be much appreciated.

Tuur

---

ok.. found it..
i have two cubes, that are being flipped around and are rigged bodies.
The 'child of' faces lose 'it' when they collide.
When i add rigid body to the faces all animation seems to be 'corrupt' ..
In the end.. i like the cubes to collide and that the 'child of' faces then 'spray' away a bit because of the collision and drop on the floor..

[image: two cubes + faces flying around]

[image: the 'child of' is gone after collision]

should i re-do the whole animation and rigid body the face from the start and make it active (or so) when they collide? I'm quite confused atm.. haha.. sorry.. noob

Answer (score 5):

Use the *Child Of* constraint. At the frame before the parent drops, create a *LocRotScale* keyframe for the child object and create a keyframe on its contraint *Influence* at 1. Next frame, create a *Visual LocRotScale* keyframe, and create a keyframe on the constraint *Influence* at 0. Don't worry if the child jumps back, it will take the visual location keyframe into account when you'll play the animation

Or use the *[Dynamic Parent](https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent/releases/download/v1.0.0/dynamic_parent_v1.0.0.zip)* addon.

As for your second question, you need to give your child object a *Rigid Body* and keyframe the *Animated* option: keyframe with the option on and when the next frame keyframe with the option off, see what it gives:

[image]

As your initial question has changed, check my new answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237742/how-to-make-2-cubes-with-child-of-faces-crash-lose-cube-parent-and-faces-spr/237744#237744).

Comment: Hi,thanks for being quick and clear!! I'll have a go with it. Thanks again! Tuuur

Comment: if you meet any difficulty, please tell me. When you'll put the Influence at 0 don't worry if the child jumps back, it will take the Visual location into account when you'll play the animation

Comment: Hi, this seems to do what i need.. i think.. but now i try to let the de-parented faces drop to the ground.. Actually, two cubes collide.. i like the 12 face to de-parent (which works) and now i like to make the faces drop to the ground following the physics...

Comment: Hello, it's hard to help without additional pictures, etc, if you want to use physics, use Rigid Body, and create keyframes on the Animated option so that physics begin to act whenever you want

Comment: thanks again! i have a go on that.. when not successful i'll prep some pics etc..