# How to make 2 cubes with 'child of' faces crash, lose cube parent, and faces spray around and drop on the floor

Tags: physics, collision

it seems i have to re-ask my question.. [delete parent halfway animation, keep position and more](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237553/delete-parent-halfway-animation-keep-position-and-more/237741#237741)

i have two cubes flying around, they are rigid bodies and have cube faces that are 'child of'.
When the cubes collide i want the 'child of' faces to lose the 'parent' and 'spray' a bit around because of the impact of the collision of the cubes and drop on the floor.
Not sure what to do..
Now i take out 'influence' at the collision moment.. but i have no glue how to reach my goal from here..
I tried to make the faces rigid bodies as well.. but then the cube doesn't do it's physics anymore..
now i'm quite confused..

[image: cube flying around as rigid bodies]

[image: faces lose child of]

Answer (score 2):

As I told you in your previous question you need to keyframe the *Rigid Body "Animated"* option: At the frame before the dropping, when they are still child of, keyframe the *Animated* box on, and the next frame, when they stop to be the child of, keyframe the *Animated* box off. Put your cursor at the beginning of the timeline and play:

[image]

File here: [image]

So as your situation is a bit different, as your cubes are subjects to physics since the beginning, what you can do is give your children (here a simple cone) a *Child Of* constraint with the cubes as parent, give them a *Physic > Rigid Body > Active*, switch off the *Dynamic* option at the beginning, keyframe the option box, switch it on when the cubes collide, keyframe the option box:

[image]

File here: [image]

Also, make sure that your objects are clean, meaning scales are 1:1:1, origine at center, etc...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129472/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-to-make-2-cubes-with-child-of-faces-cras).